# Can allies interact with mission tokens?

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

I'm playing a mission with Luke Skywalker as an ally and the mission requires that I pick up 'X' mission tokens and carry them to a location on the map.

According to [the rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/8c/53/8c53f757-cafc-4e1c-be2f-ba87efb4db92/swi01_rules_reference.pdf):

> Rebel allies are not heroes. During their activation, they
>   cannot interact with crates or rest. Rebel allies can perform
>   only one attack each activation, and follow all other rules for
>   non-hero figures.

I can't seem to find the "all other rules for non-hero figures" part.

Does this mean that Luke (or another Ally) can pick up mission tokens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never played the game, but it seems as though the rules consistently refer to either "figures" or "non-hero figures". So a hero is a special kind of figure.

Some quotes from the rules:

> During a **figure’s** activation, it may perform two actions. The available actions are Attack, Move, Interact, Rest, and Special.
>   [...]
>   A **figure** can perform the same action multiple times during the same activation except as follows:
>   - A **non-hero figure** can use only one of its actions to perform an attack per activation.
>   - A **figure** can perform each special action only once per activation.
>   [...]
>   Rebel allies are not heroes. During their activation, they cannot interact with crates or rest. Rebel allies can perform only one attack each activation, and follow all other rules for **non-hero figures**.
>   [...]
>   Some missions allow **figures** to retrieve specific tokens. A figure adjacent to or in the same space as the token can perform an interact to retrieve the token. Place the token on the figure’s base to mark that the **figure** is now carrying that token. The token now moves with the **figure**.
>   [...]
>   During a campaign, each Rebel player controls a hero. The word “Hero” is used to refer to **hero figures**, the player controlling the figure, and all of the associated components.

Since it says 'figures' in the piece about mission tokens, and does not exclude 'non-hero figures', I'd say a non-hero figure can collect mission tokens.